# wifi/wlan password only in memory not on sd-card after start

Tags: wpa-supplicant

Is there a way to place the wpa password on an USB stick, boot the raspberry and remove the USB stick afterwords such that the wpa password resides only in memory?

Comment: Any reason why?  You could try starting WiFi with the file on a USB stick if you wait till the mount has completed along the lines of `sudo wpa_supplicant -c /media/usb/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0` If it’s a security issue, I would review the use of other users rather than Pi and limiting sudo capabilities.

Comment: @Andyroo I would like to place my pi outside of the house and therefore one can tamper with the pi at will. My reasoning is, as long as nobody can login and the wpa password is not on the sd card I do not compromise my wlan.

Comment: I think I would create my own AP on the pi and bridge that to the home network in that case.